# wpdb php get_var query to get ID for URL image doesn't work for ID over 999

Tags: php, query, wpdb

I have been using the following php code in a custom plugin to successfully capture the image ID for a media image URL in Wordpress

```
  global $wpdb;
  $picture_ID = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url));
  return $picture_ID;
```

I have encountered no problems for several years and still do not as long as the ID in the wp_posts table on the URL's row is not 1000 or more.  As soon as I added a picture via the Wordpress media upload that got assigned an ID greater than 999 the code above does not work.  The code works on my local PC, but fails on the godaddy server.  Does anyone have an idea of why it would not work in both places.  I have no doubt the problem is the row ID being greater than 999.  The query simply will not return this row, at least as to how the variable $picture_ID is setup.

I am running the same version of Wordpress on both sites (4.8.1).  The PC PHP version is 5.6.30.  The server version is 5.6.31